# How to return two strings in Java?

Tags: java

Question: 
my question is how can i return another string using for loop.
..for example:
for(String Name: name & String Info:info)
any help would be appreciated ...

```
for(String Info : info)
{
    Beach contact = new Beach(image_id[count],Info);
    count++;
    list.add(contact);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by returning string using for loop?

Comment: Python or Java? Please tag correct language.

Comment: im using this in java for fetching data and putting it into recyclerview but the problem is i want to get both info and name using for loop but i can get only one at a time have tried using multiple for loops but had no use.

Comment: Again, Python or Java?

Comment: Easy, `for name, info in itertools.izip(names, infos):....`

Comment: JAVA i repeat JAVA JAVA

Comment: @marcadian can you explain in detail with and  example???

Comment: Hint: horrible horrible naming. Names should tell you something about the object they represent. Your names don't. And worse, they violate java coding guidelines; thus they just add an **enormous** amount of confusion. Example: is "info" some list of strings, then call it "informations" or something alike.

Comment: @Jägermeister seriously? `informations` tells you more than `info`? (besides the plural of information is information).

Comment: Yeah, well. The point is about the PLURAL in there, as something like infoList ... isn't too great either. On the other hand, information doesnt have a plural anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The *modified* `for` loop allows you to iterate over an `Iterable`, so basically it creates an iterator. Thus, you cannot do what you are after. What you can do, however, is something like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(name.length, info.length); i++) {
    list.add(new Beach(immage_id[++count], info[i]));
}
```

Comment: i have tried using this technique but im not able to add name, im able to add  only one string at a time .

Comment: @ShivrajPatil: In your example you are not showing how you need to use the data found within the `name` Iterable. In my example above, you would simply need to add `name[i]`.